# Mapping a Drive to File Server (Win2008) results in incorrect password / username error after Reboot or Logoff/in

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, mappeddrive

Here is the setup.  Very small network.  Windows 2008 with a single folder shared as 'Data'.  Win2k8 server (called Server) has user account called Staff that is part of Users group.  On a network attached laptop, when I go to map a network drive to \Server\Data using the Staff username and password - Server\Staff as username I can connect to the mapped drive.

Once the user reboots or logs out and back in I get an error saying: Incorrect Password Or Unknown Username and it has the password field blank.  I am putting in the SAME password I originally did for the mapped drive and I am then able to see the contents.

How do I fix it so that I don't have to put in the password every time a client machine reboots?

FYI - the is no AD on the 2k8 server, just a workgroup with local user accounts.

Comment: Why aren't you using AD?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Stored User Names and Passwords (If I remember correctly that it was called that in XP) in Control Panel for the entry. If you find it there try deleting it and recreating it.

Comment: Not visible, I think this is only available on XP machines connected to a domain, there is no domain here.

Comment: You can check for mapped drives with "net use" then. Delete any that exist and recreate them.